# Smartgit/hg not listing changed files

Tags: git, ubuntu, smartgit, git-stage

I've been trying to use SmartGit/Hg (on Ubuntu Linux, wish SourceTree was available). Just staying in the master because it's only me working and I want to get over this hurdle before I understand branches in SmartGit.

I have it on the "main" view, and looking at the "Files" section. All the top right buttons are selected except the "unchanged files" one. And then my changed files aren't listed!

However, if I select "unchanged files" button I can then see the file I have changed and select it. The "Changes" section below that can see that there are changes in the file between the "index(staged state)" and the "HEAD (repository state)". So why can't the file list notice it's been changed!!!

Please help me out. For a decent work flow I need to be able to see a list what files have changed so I can review/choose which ones to stage and then commit.

It is possible I've changed a setting and don't know where. This program isn't a great GUI to me yet, and it's seriously making me consider buying a windows laptop for 1 program!

Comment: Are you sure you have View|Staged Files selected?

Comment: Also, a screenshot of the file table would be helpful, with "unchanged files" selected, showing your modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that SmartGit does not refresh automatically on Linux (http://smartgit.3668570.n2.nabble.com/Ubuntu-Linux-View-does-not-refresh-on-window-activate-td6878844.html). Press F5 or View->Refresh. The changed files should now have the state "Modified".